# NSIS MUI - how to write custom text to install log?

Tags: nsis, nsis-mui

When copying files, I am doing few things with them... is it possible to notify user what is going on during installation in textbox that shows copied files? I was tryting to find that information in internet, but without luck... not sure what to look for...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I will answer it myself, as someone may be looking for it:

```
DetailPrint "Some text"
```

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe this will be easier to find when the search engines are able to index the now following keyword "Show details"